# Can I include a template that extends another in Tornado?

Tags: python, templates, include, tornado

I'm stumbling with an error when trying to do something as simple as including a template that extends another one... I'm not sure if that's an unsupported case or I'm doing something wrong, because it seems like a very common scenario.

The smallest code that I've managed to write to reproduce the error is this:

### test.py

```
import tornado.template
loader = tornado.template.Loader(".")
templ = loader.load("t1.html")
```

### t1.html

```
{% include "t2.html" %}
```

### t2.html

```
{% extends "t3.html" %}
```

### t3.html

```
{# empty #}
```

when running `test.py` I get a `NotImplementedError` raised in tornado's `template.py`

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Comment: I don't remember the keyword extend but what I used to do is include a different file and then modify the needed blocks to suite the new page. Try doing that.

Comment: to overwrite blocks you need to extend a template first...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, sorry, I got too focused on the missing blocks.

What you've described doesn't work using `{% include %}`, but works for me using `{% module Template('t2.html', **args) %}`, which will render the template in it's own namespace. Module setup is done automatically by `tornado.web.Application`, but not with the minimal template loader in your example.

This limitation seems to be there because of the way the `{% extends %}` tag is implemented.

Comment: That was my original case, I removed the blocks so the error could be reproduced with the bare minimum necessary code. Adding the lines you propose still makes it raise the aforementioned error.